# str.split("\\s+") Not working as expected

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am reading a line Like `2222 1555 777`

have:

```
String[] splitDist = line.split("\\s+");
for (int i = 0; i< splitDist.length; i++){
     System.out.println(i);
}
```

`i` never changes. Any reason as to why? Thoughts?

I am expecting an array like `["2222","1555","777"]`

but  it is one string `["22221555777"]` so `i` will be 0

EDIT: Not Sure as to why this is happening... Thank you all for trying, something is wrong here. this one thing just gives Just odd behavior...

Comment: "*`i` never changes*" I can't reproduce your problem. This prints `0 1 2` to me so it seems that `i` does change.

Comment: What is the **exact** input string?

Comment: Exactly as it is in the question.

Comment: Show more source code. The snipped you posted seems to work as the answers suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String[] splitDist = line.split("\\s+");
for (int i = 0; i< splitDist.length; i++){
    System.out.println(splitDist[i]);
}
```

You need to print the array element and not `i`

Comment: I understand that, BUT `i` is still supposed to change? since there are 3 values in the new array.

Comment: @TooTiredToDrink Test it with `String[] splitDist = "a b c".split("\\s+");`. You should see three lines.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
public static void main(String args[]){

 String[] arr = new String[3] ;
 String line = "2222 1555 777";
 String[] splitDist = line.split("\\s+");
 for (int i = 0; i< splitDist.length; i++){
    arr[i] = splitDist[i];
 }
 System.out.println("arr"+Arrays.deepToString(arr));
}
```

Output:

```
arr[2222, 1555, 777]
```

It is working.

Comment: This works fine for me.Could you show how you defined the input string